How insert clear button in tangerine EGRA tool app
I wan to add button clear in my EGRA assessment test. I am using Tangerine EGRA tool kit app
I am designing EGMA test . I Select the location i.e. Select District then all schools appears next combo box. Now i want to add clear button test after selection of districts detail I want to press clear button all selected information is clear. Then i reselect the option.
